# Radio Button checking and unchecking programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-layout

My requirement is to be able to be able to check only 1 radio button from the no of options available.

My layout is simple

[image]

User should be able to select only one of p1, p2 and p3.

The IDs for for the buttons are `rB1,rB2 and rB3`.

PS: I know it is possible to achieve the same with `RadioGroup` , but in this particular instance I want to go with `Radio Button` hence the query

Comment: how does the radio button is checked?? through clicking a button

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin updated the query , only 1 button needs to be selected . By defaults it allows more than 1 to be selected.

Comment: You need to use RadioGroup for this, inside RadioGroup declare your RadioButtons

Comment: @AmanSingh Mate I do not want to use radio group in this particular case due to some constraints. Though I understand where you are coming from and that is certainly easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this..

```
r1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
r2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
r3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

And `CheckedChangeListener`

```
@Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
      if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.rB1) {
        r2.setChecked(false);
        r3.setChecked(false);
      }
      if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.rB2) {
        r1.setChecked(false);
        r3.setChecked(false);
      }
      if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.rB3) {
        r1.setChecked(false);
        r2.setChecked(false);
      }
    }
  }
```

and don't forget to `implements OnCheckedChangeListener` in your activity or fragment.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be achieved by setting a `android:onClick="onRadioButtonClick"` in the `layout.xml` file and creating a `onRadioButtonClick` method in `Activity.java`

```
public void onRadioButtonClick(View v)
{
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();
    RadioButton r1  = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rB1);
    RadioButton r2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rB2);
    RadioButton r3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rB3);
    switch(v.getId()) {     

case R.id.rB1:

    if (checked){
        r2.setChecked(false);
        r3.setChecked(false);
    }
    break;

case R.id.rB2:
    if (checked){
        r1.setChecked(false);
        r3.setChecked(false);
    }
    break;

case R.id.rB2:
    if (checked){
        r1.setChecked(false);
        r2.setChecked(false);
    }   
    break;

    }
```

I am posting this soulution because I couldn't find the solution to this query on this site(when I was looking for it earlier in the day) and had to figure it out myself. This might be useful for someone else looking for a similar solution.

Comment: Why don't you use `CheckedChangeListener` see my ans. May be that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

**java**

```
public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

  private RadioGroup radioSexGroup;
  private RadioButton radioSexButton;
  private Button btnDisplay;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addListenerOnButton();

  }

  public void addListenerOnButton() {

    radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
    btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // find the radiobutton by returned id
                radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                radioSexButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });

  }
}
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioSex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_male" 
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_female" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_display" />

</LinearLayout>
```

for more detail see below link:-

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_radiogroup_control.htm

Comment: Mate this is a RadioGroup example. I am looking for Radio Button one

Comment: @misguided A RadioGroup class is used for set of radio buttons. If we check one radio button that belongs to a radio group, it automatically unchecks any previously checked radio button within the same group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/p1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="P1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/p2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="P2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/p3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="P3" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Radio group

XML:

 <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rB1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="P1" 
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rB2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="P2" />
       <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rB3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="P3" />

    </RadioGroup>
```